# Host Lightning Component on Appexchange

Tags: lightning-aura-components, appexchange

What are the possible ways to provide navigation to access lightning component in managed package? I have created lightning component tab for my lightning component. But after winter 16 , I can not see option to create lightning component tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a requirement as of Winter 16 that you have to enable the my domain feature in an org in order to use lightning components.

I suspect that the missing option to create a Lightning Components tab is due to your org not having enabled this feature.

I wrote a [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/10/important-change-to-lightning-components-in-winter-16.html) about it to explain this for the Salesforce developers blog.